# .NET application does not start at all in a client machine

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, deployment

I've developed an application ( windows forms c# ) for a client last week. but when he tries to install it, an exception was thrown about a missing component ( Visualbasic.powerpacks 10.0 ) he informed me that he tried to download the version 3.0 of the component but when installed and he tried to launch the setup of the application, it does not start at all.

I went to try the process in a another machine of mine, i executed the setup, launched the application, and the exception about Powerpacks was thrown, i downloaded the 10.0 version, installed it but when i try to launch the application, nothing happens! it loads for about 5 sec but nothing happens after.

I went to check the windows event view, and every time the application fails to launch an event appears there that has something to do with security-spp i can post the exact details of the event if needed ( since i'm writing this message from the dev machine )

I developed the application in this environment:
Visual Studio 2012
C#
Winforms

And for the reference ( powerpacks ) i copied to local by setting the variable copy local to true.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you

**EDIT :**

**SOLVED!** I set the property copy to local to true for all the references. now they are located in the release folder, take that folder to another machine and the application started. sent my client an update.

**Thank you for your answers.**

Comment: What's the error description in the Event Viewer?

Answer (score 2):

To successfully deploy an application, you must also deploy all [components that are referenced by the application.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc425002(v=vs.80).aspx)

> Users might need administrative permissions or similar user
>   permissions on the computer to install bootstrapped components. For
>   ClickOnce applications, this means that the user might need
>   administrative permissions to install the application regardless of
>   the security level specified by the application. After the application
>   is installed, the user can run the application without administrative
>   permissions.

I am assuming you and your client are running install and application `run as Administrator`.